# Login to RDS session

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, login-screen, remote-login, rds

As the moment, I have to log into my desktop, start mstsc, and type in the rds details to login to my rds desktop session.

Is it possible to go directly into the rds session without having to load my local desktop first?

For example, when the computers starts, instead of showing the desktop login screen, somehow maybe get it to show a login screen which lets me log into an rds session straight away?

Comment: You could run a script on start? Would that do?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to set this up for (Don't fall in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) you may want to buy a [Thin Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) instead.

Comment: @DaveRook, if the script means that the rds session starts with a single login, that would be great, but it would ideally to shutdown the client computer when the user logs off the rds session too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I'm trying to reuse old hardware with the current network structure.  What I don't want to do is restructure the whole network and buy new hardware.  Instead, as RDS is already working and as I already have old hardware which is perfectly good for an rds session, I just wanted to know if it's possible to fake a thin client type of system  simply by getting the rds login to appear automatically when the computer is loaded?